# change dynamic href url to another value in jquery

Tags: jquery

Good Day all  & thanks  if you looking in problem in advance

U may find it silly for my question but i am totally noob in jquery ..

my question

link 1 : [www.domain.com/jobs/abc/abc/abc](http://www.domain.com/jobs/abc/abc/abc)  // this is what is get
----i want to change jobs to vacancy other should be  same
link 1 : [www.domain.com/vacancy/abc/abc/abc](http://www.domain.com/vacancy/abc/abc/abc) // this is what i need

where should i change  so i get desired  change from jobs to vacancy

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.socialShareLinks a').each(function() {
  var value = $(this).attr('href');
  console.log(value);
  $(this).attr('href', value.replace('[ARTICLELINK]',$(location).attr('href')));
});
```

});

i know  there is preg replace  but  it is not working tried and came down for your expert suggestion guys

Comment: hi fredomn  thanks for reply, so what do u suggest ..  how should i go about it

Comment: where should i place this line  ..above  consule  log ..?

Comment: no it does not work .. when placed under   console log  it workd  but its same jobs inurl

Comment: https://html-online.com/articles/dynamic-social-media-share-widget-addthis-alternative/  this is the page  i got the code which is working perfectly grt on few pages  only this  page  i want ot change  part of url thats it

Comment: Please update your question with a snippet that includes the HTML and javascript, along with expected output (which seems to be the issue).   See here for more information on how to do this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: i think  will this do ..?

Comment: <script async src="//jsfiddle.net/mahboob123/goftL8me/embed/"></script>

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mahboob123/goftL8me/

Comment: thanks  i got it working  just  changed the href to desire and with php got it throught  thank u for your  help